# Jquery Multiple Attribute End Selector (OR)

Tags: jquery-selectors, attributes

Is there a better version of this:

```
$(a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".jpeg])
```

I'm interested for 2 reasons:

1. It is hard to take the point in visually because of the number
   of characters involved.
2. Writing it this way could potentially
   result in wasted cycles (I'm assuming).

Comment: There are no wasted cycles involved. This is especially true of browsers that support `querySelectorAll()` which would treat your selector exactly as they do were it in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$.expr[':'].img = function(obj) {
   return (/\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$/i).test(obj.href);
}
```

Then call the images like this:

```
$("a:img")
```